# Inserting Unique Data into Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently in the process of upgrading a database with SQL Server.  Currently I am trying to sanitize a table to get rid of a whole bunch of duplicate records.  However I can't seem to get my query to work properly.

```
CREATE TABLE Temp_A
(
    Order_ID INT NOT NULL,
    Job_Number VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Supplier_Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL 
);

BULK INSERT Temp_A
FROM 'This\is\the\file\path.csv'
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')

CREATE TABLE Temp_B
(
    Order_ID INT NOT NULL,
    Job_Number VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Supplier_Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL 

    CONSTRAINT Temp_Con UNIQUE (Order_ID, Job_Number)
);

INSERT INTO Temp_B
    SELECT Order_ID, Job_Number, Supplier_Name
    FROM Temp_A AS A
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                      FROM Temp_B AS B
                      WHERE B.Order_ID = A.Order_ID
                        AND B.Job_Number = A.Job_Number)
```

The part of my code that isn't working is the `INSERT INTO Temp_B` block at the end.  What I am doing is inserting the data from a CSV file into the `Temp_A` Table, then attempting to grab all the unique `Order_ID & Part_Number` pairs and store them in the `Temp_B` table.

I'd love to go in and manually delete these duplicates but there are tens of thousands of records so...yeah that would take forever.  I am not sure where to go from here.

EDIT: To add in the error message I am getting:

> Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'Temp_Con'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Temp_B'. The duplicate key value is (3, L154)

Comment: *"The part of my code that isn't working"* why isn't working? Error message? No rows?

Comment: @EzLo The duplicates are still there.

Comment: @EzLo editted to add in the error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a unique by 2 columns, but your source data has 3. Which row will you choose if you have more than 1 row with the same `Order_ID` and `Job_Number`?

Using `GROUP BY` with `MAX()`.

```
INSERT INTO Temp_B (
    Order_ID, 
    Job_Number, 
    Supplier_Name
SELECT 
    Order_ID, 
    Job_Number, 
    Supplier_Name = MAX(Supplier_Name)
FROM 
    Temp_A AS A
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 
            'not yet in Temp_B' 
        FROM 
            Temp_B AS B
        WHERE 
            B.Order_ID = A.Order_ID AND 
            B.Job_Number = A.Job_Number)
GROUP BY
    A.Order_ID,
    A.Job_Number
```

Using `ROW_NUMBER()`.

```
;WITH MissingRanked AS
(
    SELECT 
        Order_ID, 
        Job_Number, 
        Supplier_Name,
        Ranking = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY 
                A.Order_ID, 
                Job_Number 
            ORDER BY 
                (SELECT NULL)) -- Your ordering criteria here
    FROM 
        Temp_A AS A
    WHERE 
        NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 
                'not yet in Temp_B' 
            FROM 
                Temp_B AS B
            WHERE 
                B.Order_ID = A.Order_ID AND 
                B.Job_Number = A.Job_Number)
)
INSERT INTO Temp_B (
    Order_ID, 
    Job_Number, 
    Supplier_Name
SELECT
    Order_ID, 
    Job_Number, 
    Supplier_Name
FROM
    MissingRanked AS M
WHERE
    M.Ranking = 1
```

Comment: I assume the 'Using Row_Number()' is suppose to be in the code block?  And the reason why I am only declaring 2 of the columns as unique instead of the 3 is that for each pair of the two columns i am looking for there should not be a different third column.  Looking at my data I found an instance or two where it actually is different, but it isn't SUPPOSE to be different

Comment: @Skitzafreak you can just run it as is

Answer (score 0):

I would try making my INSERT INTO unique with GROUP by instead like this:

```
INSERT INTO Temp_B
SELECT Order_ID, Job_Number, Supplier_Name
FROM Temp_A AS A
GROUP BY A.Order_ID, A.Job_Number, A.Supplier_Name
```

I don't have the data to test against but I think this would work.  Your question has `Order_ID & Part_Number` but the join written didn't, I'm guessing a type-o but you get the idea of.  This is the direction I'd go with though.  You could also use `DISTINCT` but I like `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 0):

Your approach does not work because the subselect sees the records as they were before the insert - that is it sees an empty table.

What you need instead is the DISTINCT keyword.

```
INSERT INTO Temp_B
SELECT DISTINCT Order_ID, Job_Number, Supplier_Name
FROM Temp_A
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add DISTINCT keyword in INSERT query:

```
INSERT INTO Temp_B
SELECT DISTINCT Order_ID, Job_Number, Supplier_Name
FROM Temp_A AS A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1 FROM Temp_B AS B
WHERE B.Order_ID = A.Order_ID
AND B.Job_Number = A.Job_Number);
```

Comment: Adding DISTINCT did not work as a fix.  I am still getting the same error as I was before (see editted OP for error message), only this time with a different value pair.